# Firebase Firestore Distributed Counter - No Properties to Serialize Found

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, counter

I've already read and changed my code according to what is recommended in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505916/firebase-firestore-distributed-counter-documentation-code-crashing).

However, my problem still persists, getting the same error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.blush.android.blush.chat.chatCloudCommunications.ChatCloudSentMessageToFirestore$Counter
```

I'm running everything below inside a public class called *ChatCloudSentMessageToFirestore*. I've left out the "createCounter", "getCounter" and "incrementCounter" which are defined in the same class. I do this in order to keep the code short, and because they're identical to what's defined on the Firebase Firestore website: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters so are unlikely to be the cause of the error (unless they need any modification that I'm unaware of).

```
public class Counter {
    int numShards;

    public Counter(int numShards) {
        this.numShards = numShards;
    }
}

// counters/${ID}/shards/${NUM}
public static class Shard {
    int count;

    public Shard(){}

    public Shard(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

I also have this reference within the same class:

```
DocumentReference counterChrisDocRef = db.collection("users")
        .document("ypiXrobQxuZ0wplN5KO8gJf934")
        .collection("conversations")
        .document("conversation0") //Specified conversation
        .collection("messageCounter")
        .document("shards");
```

and I'm trying to use the counters in this method:

```
public void addSentMessageToFirestoreDB(final Map<String, Object> messageSent) {
    WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

    createCounter(counterChrisDocRef, 1);

    incrementCounter(counterChrisDocRef, 1);


    DocumentReference chrisSentMessageRef = db.collection("users")
            .document("ypiXrobQxuZ0wplN5KO8gJf934")
            .collection("conversations")
            .document("conversation0") //Specified conversation
            .collection("messages")
            .document("message" +  getCount(counterChrisDocRef) + " (sent)");

    batch.set(chrisSentMessageRef, messageSent);

    batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't using public getters for your fields in your classes at all, please make all your fields `public` because in your code are now default. In order to set values directly on your fields, your fields must be `public`. If you want to have your fields private, just add the corresponding public getters and everything will work fine.

Please also remove the `static` keyword from your `Shard` class. There is no need to make that class `static`.